# Explain scala nested function from book 'Programming in Scala 2'nd edition'

Tags: scala

What is the meaning of <- clause in below code ?
Is it like an assignment ?

```
class Nested {

  var filesHere = (new java.io.File(".")).listFiles()

  def fileLines(file: java.io.File) =
    scala.io.Source.fromFile(file).getLines().toList

  def grep(pattern: String) =
    for (
      file <- filesHere 
      if (file.getName.endsWith(".scala"));
      line <- fileLines(file) 
      if line.trim().matches(pattern)
    ) println(file + ": " + line.trim)

}
```

Comment: The book tells you what it is at the start of that very section...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not quite like an assignment: more like a for-each loop, but better.  You can read about it [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/111).

```
scala> for(i <- List(1,2,3,4)) println(i)
1
2
3
4
```

So this basically says, for each individual item `i` in the collection `List(1,2,3,4)`, call `println(i)`.

Answer (score 1):

I pronounce `<-` as "in". So I would read the code as "for each file in filesHere ...". The operator plays the same role as the `:` operator in Java foreach loops.

Answer (score 0):

I consider this as a "for each ... from" syntax, so I would read your example

```
for (
  file <- filesHere
  ...
)
```

as:
"for each file from filesHere"